# routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat Getting Crash

Tags: iphone, distance, skmaps

I am Using Skobbler map.

get crash on  audio advice method, `routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat`

```
NSArray* advices = [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat:SKDistanceFormatMetric];
```

method in SKMAP

IOS Version : 7.1
Xcode :5.1.1

Comment: Which language are you targeting? Are the language files present in SkAdvisor.Resources.bundle (in the languages folder?)

Comment: If the question is solved, can you also add & accept your own answer? This way, other might benefit from your experience.

Comment: I don't Know why it happen. I just removed  Exception Break point. When I put Exception break point It crashed.